# Best way to refactor acces to array elements

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

a have an external dll, which returns array of user information depending on provided itemIDs. A simple code for that, could be:

```
private string userName;
private int userAge;

const string NAME = "NAME";
const string AGE = "AGE";

string[] arrID = { NAME, AGE }; //IDs to get name and age, to get surname please add "SURNAME" to the array

User[] users; 
string[] results; //OK - item found, Unknown - item id not found

////////read from external dll////////
databaseAccessor.GetUsers(arrID, out users, out results);
//////////////////////////////////////

int itemNameIndex = Array.IndexOf(arrID, NAME);
int itemAgeIndex = Array.IndexOf(arrID, AGE);

if(results[itemNameIndex] == "OK")
{
    userName = users[itemNameIndex].Name;
}

if(results[itemAgeIndex] == "OK")
{
    userAge = users[itemAgeIndex].Age;
}
```

I don't like this code as, as there must be added a new if clause, when trying to get a new user "feature" e.g. height. One thing, that cannot be changed is the call to external dll `databaseAccessor.GetUsers(arrID, out users, out results);`

What would be the best way to refactor it to avoid adding new ifs?

Comment: Show us how the class `User` looks like.

Comment: I don't get what the contents of the results array and the users array are... It appears that the results array contains a result for each FIELD you requested (like "NAME" and "AGE"), but you access the users array with the same index (itemNameIndex and itemAgeIndex). Could you give an example of the array contents that are returned by your external DLL?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could create a wrapper class for the external call en interpret the results in there. Then you can make sure only valid user entities are returned which would be instances of a separate user entity class as well with properties like Name and Age. That would make it cleaner in my opinion (and easier to swap out the external dll if need be). Something like:

```
IEnumerable<UserEntity> users = UserManager.Get();
```

Then just implement all the code you need to access the users in `UserManager.Get`. You could off course then create some private methods to access information from the array. Like TryGetValue which does the check on `results[itemNameIndex] == "OK"` and then returns the value.

So wrap it and make the code to retrieve the values a bit more generic would be my advice.